# Changing the theme of an app in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to create a theme selector for my app. For some reason when I start the app the theme isn't initially set which is what I believe is the issue (error thrown is, TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating theme.primary)). Also when the app starts it doesnt display a current theme until after clicking the button. Im new to react-native so Im sure there is a simple solution I missed.

Here is my settings page which has a button that should change the theme from red to dark and back.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from 'react-native';
import styles from '../constants/Layout';
import { themes } from '../constants/Colors';

export let theme = themes.dark;

export default class SettingScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { appTheme: themes.dark };
        this.changeTheme = this.changeTheme.bind(this);
    }

    changeTheme() {
        theme = this.state.appTheme === themes.dark ? themes.red : themes.dark;
        this.setState({ appTheme: theme });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text style={styles.text}>
                    Settings{"\n"}
                    Current theme: {this.state.appTheme}
            </Text>
                <Button
                    onPress={this.changeTheme}
                    title='Change Theme'
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
};
```

The color set file is as follows,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export const themes = {
    dark,
    red,
};

// Dark theme
const dark = {
    primary: '#424242',
    primLight: '#6d6d6d',
    primDark: '#1b1b1b',
    text: '#ffffff',
    accent: '#ff0000',
};

// Red theme
const red = {
    primary: '#d32f2f',
    primLight: '#ff6659',
    primDark: '#9a0007',
    text: '#ffffff',
    accent: '#000000',
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what property is primary?

Comment: this is where im slightly confused, i was trying to set like a color package.. so dark has a primary color, a primary light, etc. Should i make those variables and set them equal to their colors?

Comment: const dark = {
    'primary' : '#424242',
    'primLight' : '#6d6d6d',
    'primDark' : '#1b1b1b',
    'text' : '#ffffff',
    'accent' : '#ff0000',
}; should it be more like this?

Comment: @JoshGarvey hey, this will apply dark theme for the whole app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You export `null` object, to correct it, just move `export const themes` after assign value to `dark, red`

```html
import React, { Component } from 'react';

// Dark theme
const dark = {
    primary: '#424242',
    primLight: '#6d6d6d',
    primDark: '#1b1b1b',
    text: '#ffffff',
    accent: '#ff0000',
};

// Red theme
const red = {
    primary: '#d32f2f',
    primLight: '#ff6659',
    primDark: '#9a0007',
    text: '#ffffff',
    accent: '#000000',
};

export const themes = {
    dark,
    red,
};
```

Comment: Awesome that solved my null error! I knew it was something simple I was missing.